# In ionic How to call a method when device backbutton tapped in open modal?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

In fallowing code I try to call a method when in open modal the device back button taped.

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
       platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
         if(this.navCtrl.canGoBack()){
              this.navCtrl.pop();
            }else{
              this.closeModal(this.closeme)
            }

       });
```

But it dos not work

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to disable device/hardware back button in open modal or assign a method or function for button.

Comment: Then you have to implement the logic inside the modal.